# Issue Bootstrap Navbar css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have a bootstrap navbar with some custom code to be able to use 2nd level submenus. The issue I'm having is when I click Menu Item 1, then sub 1(or sub 2) to open a 2nd level submenu, the li item containing sub 1 or sub 2 shows a white background whenever the mouse is off this sub 1 or sub 2 item. Any help to remove this white background would be really appreciated. I have tried many things without success. The bootply is here : http://www.bootply.com/sugW3tvaLT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your CSS code:

```
.nav .open>a, .nav .open>a:focus, .nav .open>a:hover {
    background-color: #000080 !important;
}
```

This will overwrite the default color that bootstrap is applying.

[Here is the updated **Bootply** code link](http://www.bootply.com/sqltAx086f)

Answer (score 0):

go to your `bootstrap.css` file find there `.nav .open > a, .nav .open > a:focus, .nav .open > a:hover` replace *background-color* `#EEE` to the color what you want to show on `active`